# Where to load custom UI elements in View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

If I'd like to add custom UI elements from code, where should I create them? In the layoutSubviews method or somewhere else? Also, when creating a button, is there anything special that I need to add besides the usual UIButton code?

Let's say you have a View Controller named VC and a subclass of UIView called TheMenu. The VC has a button that will have the TheMenu slide in from the left. It will somewhat resemble the sliding menus on apps such as Facebook.

I understand that in the VC class, I could simply call a UIView as follows:

```
-(void)addItemsToVC
{
    self.uiview = [[TheMenu alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(some numbers)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.uiview];
}
```

and it would instantiate a new object of TheMenu class to be used on my VC. Just trying to figure out where to build my items on TheMenu and if they need any extra lines of TLC that might not appear in a normal button build such as:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton new];
button.frame = CGRectMake:(some numbers);
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor someColor];
button.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor someColor];
button.titleLabel.text = @"some title";
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you want to do it all in code, then put any subview setup for TheMenu (like the button code you show) in its initWithFrame: method.

Comment: Certainly not in the layoutSubviews, since that gets called on rotation as well. Creating them there would add another one of them on each rotation. layoutSubviews is used, as its name suggests, laying out already existing subviews.

Answer (score 0):

I always prefer loading view content from an XIB file or storyboard to loading creating them in code.

If you're using storyboards, you could put a container view in your view controller, create a second view controller for your controls tray, and then control-drag an embed segue from your container view onto your controls tray view controller's scene. Then you would have a separate view controller that would manage the controls, and you would probably need to define one or more protocols to communicate between view controllers.

Another approached I've used is to create the view in a separate VC, and load it using `loadNibNamed:owner:options:'. You make the file's owner on the other XIB file be the same as your view controller, and hook up outlets outlets/actions as needed on the secondary XIB file. Those outlets will be nil, but when you execute the call to`loadNibNamed:owner:options:', the system will load your extra views. You can make the outermost "tray" view invisible at first. Then add code that shifts it off-screen, makes it visible, and animates it back on-screen so it slides onto the screen. You can use this "extra XIB file" approach in a storyboard-based app as well.

Comment: I created TheMenu so that it can be called on many different screens with a button press. The UIView shows on button press but is missing it's contents. In the layoutSubviews I've called [super layoutSubviews]; then added the necessary objects I wish to show on my view, but they aren't showing. I think I'm missing something within the layoutSubview method, possibly something in the code for the objects on the UIView, or possibly a different method for creating the buttons and so forth to appear on that UIView.

Comment: Once I get the answer, I'll be posting my way of creating the sliding menu that seems to be much easier than other tutorials I've seen.

Comment: You're not supposed to add/remove views in layoutSubviews. That is for laying out the position of views, not adding/removing. Why are you waiting until a button press to add subviews to your "drawer" view? You can have the whole this set up with all it's contents, but either hidden, moved off-screen, or both, and then show it and/or move it on-screen with a button press.

Answer (score 0):

I second Duncan C's idea of creating a second view controller for your menu and using storyboard segues to connect it to your other view controllers. I don't see any reason not to, because any view controller can pass whatever data the other view controller needs via the prepareForSegue method.

Comment: If you'd like to second someones answer, please use the upvote instead of adding another answer.

Comment: I hope someone can comment on this after I comment so that I can later add the way I performed the slide menu. It was quite simple compared to so many other methods out there and doesn't involve someone else's library. I have to wait until tomorrow morning as I don't have the "street cred" to answer it immediately. I don't want to delete this in case others can use it as Duncan has some great knowledge that I feel others could benefit from. I just know trying to find a way to implement the side menu wasn't fruitful and my way is easy for many. Have a great weekend all.

Comment: I don't understand. With limited reputation you can't comment twice in a row? If my answer (using a second view controller and an embed segue?) solved your problem then you should accept my answer and post a comment (or edit your question) explaining what you did.

Comment: @LordZsolt:  I gave Duncan C's answer an up vote.  I wanted to add something to his answer.  Tom:  Using someone else's library can actually help you.  That would mean less code you have to write.

Comment: I didn't use your method Duncan, I just got mine to work. It was all in setting the button's properties such as title and so forth. Once I changed those around, it worked just fine. I was just commenting that Duncan's method also made sense, but I won't rest on an issue that I know should work until I find out the answer. I will post on Monday all the stuff I did to make a slide out menu. Have a great weekend.

Comment: Tom, if you found your own solution you should post your own answer and accept it. That way people know you've solved your problem.